# Laravel Cleaner Url issue in ubuntu, How to fix it?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, laravel, laravel-4

I'm Using laravel latest version. I just added a new route but it's not working.

```
    Route::get('/about',function()
{
   return View::make('about'); 
});
```

When i type localhost/index.php/about it starts working.
So i checked some articles they suggest to edit .htaccess and i did the same.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it again didn't work so did some changes in my config file. This is the content of my config file.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sar.dev
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/public"
        <Directory "/var/www/laravel/public">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory> 
    </VirtualHost>
```

This method also failed. I'm working on ubuntu 13.10. Is there any other way to fix it ?

Comment: Have you enabled rewrite_module?

Comment: Make sure you activate rewrite_module, or just switch to NGINX :)

Comment: A really simple way to check if you've rewrite_module enabled is by removing some characters from the code inside it. E.g. change `RewriteCond` to `MyWrongCond`. You should get 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: You could also try adding a `/` to the `index.php/$1` line so that it is like this: `^(.*)$ /index.php/$1`. I have noticed this has worked for me in the past with some similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

To go with my comment. I noticed you were using a modified `.htaccess` that is not the default for laravel.

Give the laravel default `.htaccess` file a try with the `/` next to the `index.php` part.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This solution has helped me when coming across a similar error where the site would not work when going to /route and had to use /index.php/route as you are.